# MySQL via SSH Tunnel Access Denied

Tags: mysql, pdo, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I want to use SSH tunnel to connect to MySQL DB on remote host.

I've set up the tunnel with command:

```
ssh user@host -L 3307:remote_mysql_hostname:3306
```

I can successfull connect with HeidiSQL using this settings:

```
hostname: localhost
user: remote_mysql_user_login
password: remote_mysql_user_password
port: 3307
```

But when i use PDO in PHP to connect, i get:

> Access denied for user 'remote_mysql_user_login'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

My PDO Dns is sth like this:

```
mysql:type=Core_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql;host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=db_name;
```

Where is the trick?

---

**Solution:**

**@symcbean** thanks!

The problem was (as suggested by @symcbean) in hostname.

Changing to '127.0.0.1' fix the problem.**

Comment: try using 127.0.0.1. When mysql sees 'localhost' it tries to connect via a filesystem socket (faster and more relaible) instead of a network socket

Answer (score 2):

I borrowed from your example and was able to connect to a remote host using your same SSH tunnel setup. Can you share the PHP script you are using to get some more info about your setup?

You may try a hostname other than 'localhost' for your remote database you are connecting to.

setup ssh tunnel - I setup an entry in /etc/hosts for my_db_host_name instead of using localhost

ssh my_user@my_remote_host -L 3307:my_db_host_name:3306

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:host=my_db_host_name;dbname=my_db;port=3307';
$username = 'my_user';
$password = 'my_pass';
$options = array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
); 

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

$result = $dbh->query("select * from my_table");

try {
    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo "column1: " . $row['column1'];
    }
} catch (PDOException $pde) {
    echo "PDO exception: $pde";
}

echo "done \n";

?>
```